# Add item in array with index - react redux and redux-saga

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I try to update my state when adding an item in array, using react/redux and redux-saga middleware. But where I do this, I have an array, where each item have an index (0, 1, 2....) but when I add the new item (named step), the new item doesn't have an index but it is like :

```
[
  0: item1,
  1: item2,
  2: item3,
  step: newItem
]
```

And I want that the new item have an index `like 3: newItem`

Here is the reducer :

```
export function stepReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Actions.CREATE_STEP_REQUEST:
            return state;
        case Actions.STEP_CREATED:
            let newArray = action.steps.slice();
            newArray.splice(action.index, 0, action.step);
            return newArray;
        case Actions.FETCH_TRAVEL_STEPS_REQUIRED:
            return state;
        case Actions.TRAVEL_STEPS_DATA_SUCCESS:
            let updatedSteps = _.merge(action.steps, state.steps);
            return updatedSteps;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the saga file :

```
export function* createStep(action) {
    const step = yield call(stepApi.createStep, action.travelId, action.step, action.authToken);
    const steps = yield select((state) => state.steps);
    const index = steps.length; 
    yield put({ type: Actions.STEP_CREATED, steps, step, index });
}
```

if someone should help,

thank !

Comment: [_.merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) works with objects not arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are working with `lodash`, note that `_.merge` [works with objects not arrays](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge).

If you just want to add a new item to the **END** of an array you can use the [ES2015 spread feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_array_literals):

```
const nextState = [...state, action.step];
```

Comment: If I use this, I don't have an index, but `[step: NewItem]`

Comment: that's impossible as arrays doesn't have keys. and `nextState` according to my example is an array.

Comment: Thanks guy you're right for the `_.merge`, and now It work well !